# Logging out of App Actions Test Tool in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, app-actions

I logged into the App Actions Test Tool with the wrong google account, and would like to log out so I can try a different account. I can't find an option to do so.

I have already tried uninstalling and installing the plugin. Has anybody been able to log out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a login button in the top right corner of android studio, sign out of your old google account there and login with a new one. This will fix the issue.